# Why can I use a typedef of a type that doesn't exist?

Tags: c

The following small program compiles on gcc and runs fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct foo dne;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    dne *dne_var = malloc(sizeof(void*));
    printf("%p\n", dne_var);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the typedef valid?

Comment: You're allocating enough space for a pointer, not a `dne`.

Comment: As soon as you said `struct foo` you created the type. It's an incomplete type, but it exists.

Comment: Interesting - I guess this has nothing to do specifically with the `typedef`. If I remove it and replace instances of `dne` with `struct foo`, it still compiles. I guess it's more the implicit declaration I was confused about.

Comment: `dne *dne_var = malloc(sizeof(dne*));` should have been `dne *dne_var = malloc(sizeof *dne_var);`.  Then an error would occur.

Comment: Oh, I don't know how I didn't catch that I was doing the wrong thing with that malloc. It wasn't the point of confusion anyway, so I'll change it to make the question more pointed.

Comment: Another incomplete type you might be more familiar with is `void` ; you can't have `void x;`, but you can have pointers to void. However, `void` cannot be completed whereas an incomplete struct type can later be completed.

Comment: Always [cast the data pointer to void *](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751722/usage-of-void-pointers-across-different-platforms/26751747#26751747) before printing using `%p`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line

```
typedef struct foo dne;
```

implicitly declares an (incomplete at this point) structure `struct foo`. A pointer to an incomplete type is a complete type, so e.g. it’s size is known and you can declare an object of that type. However, `struct foo` itself isn’t complete until you provide a full declaration of it, so e.g.

```
dne dne_var;
```

or dereferencing your pointer to access the fields of the structure would be invalid.