# Usage of void pointers across different platforms

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, format-specifiers

I have heard that pointers should first be cast to void to ensure consistency of values across different platforms and should use `%p` format specifier. Why is it and what exactly are the problems?

```
int x=100;
int *pi=&x;
printf("value of pi is: %p",(void*)pi);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`printf` is a variadic function and must be passed arguments of the right types. The standard says `%p` takes `void *`.

[Implicit cast doesn't take place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751361/understanding-implicit-casts-in-c/26751407#26751407) for [variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Quoting from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) **7.21.6.1 The fprintf function**

> p :  The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>   manner.

Comment: Notice that the your citation is surely POSIX-specific, IIRC the standard mandates just that two different pointers have a different implementation-specific output.

Comment: Nice quoting, but in practice, how could the fact that **implicit cast doesn't take place** affect the value of the passed argument (in other words, how can a cast to `void*` make the value of `pi` any different)?

Comment: @barakmanos C specs don't require the size of `void *` and `T *` (where T is a non-void type) to be the same. A variadic implementation may decide to push different number of bytes in case of pointer to `void` and pointer to (say) `int`. But `printf` would fetch the value of this pointer as type `void *` and will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 8):

Internal presentation or size of different pointer types is not necessarily same.

For example on one system `sizeof(void*)` may be 2, but `sizeof(int*)` is 1.

Since `printf` is variable argument function, it cannot check the types of incoming parameters. If you passed `int*` to it, it would read wrong number of bytes, because it expects `void*`.

Answer (score 8):

`p` conversion specification in `printf` requires an argument of type `void *`. C says if you pass an argument of an other type the call invokes undefined behavior.

Besides that, pointer objects of different types are not required to have the same representation: C does not guarantee that `sizeof (void *) == sizeof (int *)` for example. C only guarantees that `void *` has the same representation as pointers to character types.

Comment: I wouldn't say "Besides that", but rather "That's because": if #2 weren't the case, there were no reason for #1. Meaning, if all pointers would look like each other in terms of memory layout, there would be no need to specify UB for non-`void` `*`.

Comment: @glglgl I still prefer "besides that" because in addition to C saying that *Pointers to other types need not have the same
representation or alignment requirements* there is a specific C rule for `fprintf` functions that says the argument for `p` shall be a pointer `void *`.

Comment: YOu are right, but the interconntection between the two remains.

Comment: I'm curious... could you give an example of a system or compiler where `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(T*)` (`T` being anything)?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I know systems where pointer representation is different between different pointer types but I don't know any system with different sizes for different object pointer types. I would also be curious to know if such a system exists in real life.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-siz