# Is there any difference between address of array and array itself?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address

The following code snippet proofs that both are the same:

```
int a[4];
printf("a: %p\n&a: %p", a, &a);
"0x12345678"
"0x12345678"
```

But the compiler will warn in case of:

```
int a[4], *p;
p = &a;
```

> assignment from incompatible pointer type

Which pointer type does `&a` have ?

Comment: @haccks sir, in this particular question, casting the arguments to `void *` is a required part. I would like to ask you for a reconsideration of marking this as dupe. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh; Check it again :)

Comment: @haccks Thanks for the edit, but that does not invalidate my earlier comment, either. :-)

Answer (score 3):

To be correct, first, your print statement should look like

```
 printf("a: %p\n&a: %p", (void *)a, (void *)&a);
```

because `%p` expects a `void *` argument. Please, note, [`printf()` being a variadic function, implicit conversion (cast) won't take place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26751722/2173917), so, the casting is required.

Now, that said, `a` being an array,

- `a` is of type `int [4]`
- `&a` is if type `int (*)[4]`

(but, both will return the *same* address, FWIW.) You can also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30892273/2173917).

OTOH, in your case, `p` is of type `int *`.

That's why your compiler warns you about the type mismatch in the assignment.

Comment: @Quentin sadly, the dupe won't address the casting part required in `printf()` in this case.

Comment: `&a[0]` `a` and `&a` all have the same address but of different types

Comment: @Gopi `a` is the same as `&a[0]` after decaying.

Comment: `p=&a` fires a warning (but works). Why throws `p=a` not a warning since `int *` is not `int [4]`. Is `int (*)[4]` similar to a pointer to pointer type ?

Comment: @mr.wolle I've updated my answer with a link, please check that. :-)